# Base64 Over HTTP POST losing data (Objective-C)

Tags: php, ios, objective-c, xcode, http

I currently have a HTTP POST Request and a Base64 Encoding Library, I encode my image to B64 then send it over HTTP via the POST method.

I output the Base64 to XCodes console, copy and paste it and it works perfectly. Although the Base64 I store within the Database (MongoDB, Plain Text File etc) always comes out corrupt on the other end.

Working Version (Copied and Pasted from XCode): http://dontpanicrabbit.com/api/working.php
Broken Version (From MongoDB Database): http://dontpanicrabbit.com/api/grabimage.php

If you view the source you'll notice they are the same but there is added whitespace into the broken version.

The Objective-C code I am using is:

```
MyImage.image = [info objectForKey:UIImagePickerControllerOriginalImage];

    NSData *imageData = UIImageJPEGRepresentation(MyImage.image, 0);

    [Base64 initialize];
    NSString *encoded = [Base64 encode:imageData];

    NSString *urlPOST = encoded;
    //NSLog(@"%@",encoded);

    NSString *varyingString1 = @"picture=";
    NSString *varyingString2 = urlPOST;
    NSString *post = [NSString stringWithFormat: @"%@%@", varyingString1, varyingString2];
    NSLog(@"%@", post);
    //NSString *post = @"image=%@",urlPOST;
    NSData *postData = [post dataUsingEncoding:NSASCIIStringEncoding allowLossyConversion:YES];

    NSString *postLength = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d", [postData length]];

    NSMutableURLRequest *request = [[NSMutableURLRequest alloc] init];
    [request setURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"url/api/insertimage.php"]];
    [request setHTTPMethod:@"POST"];
    [request setHTTPBody:postData];
    NSData *returnData = [NSURLConnection sendSynchronousRequest: request returningResponse: nil error: nil];
    NSString *strResult = [[NSString alloc] initWithData:returnData encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
```

PHP -> MongoDB Storage

```
<?php
    try {
      // open connection to MongoDB server
      $conn = new Mongo('localhost');

      // access database
      $db = $conn->dablia;

      // access collection
      $collection = $db->images;

      // insert a new document
      $item = array(
        'picture' => $_POST['picture']
      );
      $collection->insert($item);
      echo 'Inserted document with ID: ' . $item['_id'];

      // disconnect from server
      $conn->close();
    } catch (MongoConnectionException $e) {
      die('Error connecting to MongoDB server');
    } catch (MongoException $e) {
      die('Error: ' . $e->getMessage());
    }
?>
```

Output Code:

```
<?php
try {
  // open connection to MongoDB server
  $conn = new Mongo('localhost');

  // access database
  $db = $conn->dablia;

  // access collection
  $collection = $db->images;

  // execute query
  // retrieve all documents
  $cursor = $collection->find();

  // iterate through the result set
  // print each document
  foreach ($cursor as $obj) {
    echo '<img src="data:image/jpeg;base64,'.trim($obj['picture']).'">';
  }

  // disconnect from server
  $conn->close();
} catch (MongoConnectionException $e) {
  die('Error connecting to MongoDB server');
} catch (MongoException $e) {
  die('Error: ' . $e->getMessage());
}
?>
```

I have no idea why I seem to be corrupting over POST?

Comment: Base64 encoded data can contain '+' characters. In x-www-form-urlencoded data (as I expect your POSTed data is) the receiver knows that '+' is an encoding of a space character. Thus since you aren't URL encoding your base64 value, any instances of '+' will cause the data to be corrupted when received. That may or may not be what you're experiencing, but you will experience it at some point.

Comment: I think the problem is Whitespace when PHP gets outputted, I have compared both working (direct copy paste from convert) and php's database version, it seems there is whitespace and line returns in the source of the PHP version, this is causing it to break, I have tried trim() around the echo but no avail

Comment: So your $_POST['picture'] value is identical to what you log from the iOS application? Also, if you think the problem is when you output the value in PHP, perhaps you should include that code in your question?

Comment: It's identical but there is whitespace, lots of whitespace, which I think is the issue, I will include the code anyway

Comment: I don't suppose you can post (or link to?) samples of the correct data, and the data with the extra whitespace?

Comment: Updated the post with the links :)

Comment: What is PHP side code take POST with remove %2B?

Comment: do u know ho to convert this code to objective c : $key = "ygXa6pBJOWSAClY/J6POVTjvJpMIiPAMQiTMjBIkHnM=";
$key = (string)base64_decode($key);

Answer (score 45, accepted):

The problem is exactly what I suggested in my first comment. That is, base64 encoded data can contain '+' characters. In x-www-form-urlencoded data the receiver knows that '+' is an encoding of a space character. Thus since you aren't URL encoding your base64 value, any instances of '+' will cause the data to be corrupted when received.

The '+' characters in your initial data are turning into ' ' when received and stored. When you then output that value, it is invalid base64 encoded data.

If you examine the source of your working vs. non-working examples you'll see that the whitespace exists EXACTLY where there is a '+' in the original Base64 encoded value. Any newlines you're seeing are because whatever you're viewing the source in is wrapping lines at a ' ' character.

In your iOS code you need to properly encode the base64 encoded value, in your case all you really need to do is percent encode the '+' characters.

EDIT to add, in response to comment:

```
post = [post stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@"+" withString:@"%2B"];
```

Comment: Just gave this ago using  `post = [post stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@"+" withString:@"%"];` and now the string isn't stored at all inside Mongo, although XCode is chucking it out inside it's console. PHP echos out Null, I added the line underneath the concatenation line below VaryString 1 & 2

Comment: I have the same problem and now resolved follow your instruction ! Thanks so much :D

Comment: Thanks so much for saving my time !!

Comment: Thank you sooo much