# base64 strings objective-c to php

Tags: php, ios, objective-c, xml

I have this code here that convert a XML file inside a string to base64 and send it to my server in POST method:

```
NSData *data2 = [[NSData alloc] initWithContentsOfFile:filePath];

data2 = [data2 base64EncodedDataWithOptions:0];

NSString *base64Decoded = [[NSString alloc]
                           initWithData:data2 encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
```

When PHP receive this base64 text I try to decode it using this code:

```
$xmlFile = base64_decode($_POST['filexml']);

$file = fopen($filename.".xml","w");
fwrite($file,$xmlFile);
fclose($file);
```

When I do this the XML comes with a strange way with no sense.

The problem is with the `base64_decode` in PHP, If I go to objective-c and execute this code to convert the base64 strings to real string I see in console the correct XML file with no strange letters:

```
NSData *decodedData = [[NSData alloc] initWithBase64EncodedString:base64Decoded options:0];
    NSString *decodedString = [[NSString alloc] initWithData:decodedData encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
    NSLog(@"Decode String Value: %@", decodedString);
```

Now If I save the file without using `base64_decode` in PHP I see the same base64 strings that I see in the console using Objective-c, How to solve this problem and decode this base64 with PHP?

> Solved

My thanks to the user `hakre` and `rob` that show me [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14802715/base64-over-http-post-losing-data-objective-c) link, that contain the answer for my question:

The problem is with  x-www-form-urlencoded that recognize that the '+' is a space string character, to solve this problem I need to convert this + to %2B like this:

```
base64Decoded = [base64Decoded stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@"+" withString:@"%2B"];
```

Comment: Use `- base64EncodedStringWithOptions:` instead of `base64EncodedDataWithOptions` combining the 2nd&3rd statements.

Comment: Why are you base64 encoding XML file at all? Just send it directly. To use base64 encoding just makes both ends more complicated and slows down the transmission. If you persist in base64 encoding it, you might want to show us (a) the start of the original file; (b) what the start of the base64 encoded string looked like on client side; (c) show us how you created request; and (d) show us what `filexml` looked like before and after base 64 decoding.

Comment: Also, if you're taking a base64 string and including it in a `POST` request, if this was a simple `application/x-www-form-urlencoded` request, did you percent escape the base64 encoded string (so that the `+` characters would be escaped)? Or are you doing `multipart/formdata` request?

Comment: @Rob I have a code written in objective-c that do this, but I need to send to some informations like, name of file, id, password, and using my code I can only send the data....

Comment: Understood, but you're saying that the request is not being received correctly, but neither show us how you prepared and sent the request, nor show us what it the request looks like. We cannot possibly help you on the basis of the information provided thus far.

Comment: *"a strange way with no sense."* Strange? The only thing strange I find here is using the word strange to describe a technical problem. So please edit your question so that strange isn't a single word here but you explicitly make clear what you mean here. "no sense." is pretty much the same. It makes no sense to just tell it makes no sense to not make clear what and why makes sense to you and what and why you experienced excatly like in values and data it makes no sense any longer to you. Make your problem more clear as @rob wrote.

Comment: Have you checked http://stackoverflow.com/q/14802715/367456 ?

Comment: @hakre, Man You solve my problem, Thank you so much.

Comment: Well, this is what @Rob commented hours abo. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29572939/base64-strings-objective-c-to-php?noredirect=1#comment47296439_29572939 - you should perhaps ask about the parts you don't understand instead of thinking there are parts you must understand that you don't and then you skip asking about what actually interests you. Just a tip.

Comment: Hum, I understand thanks for this tip, will help me a lot in future.