# Encrypt NSString (NOT NSData) in iOS -> send to PHP server -> let PHP server decrypt it?

Tags: php, ios, objective-c, encryption, aes

I know there is openSSL but I just want to use encryption.

Here is exactly what I wish to do.

1) encrypt **NSString** in xcode(objective-c) with AES-128 or whatever encryption method that works

2) send the encrypted NSString to PHP server using POST method. The parameter that will be sent to PHP server would look something like:

```
 @"fromClient1=string1&fromClient2=string2"
```

3) PHP server receives that data with something like this:

```
 $receivedStr1 = $_POST['fromClient1']; // string1
 $receivedStr2 = $_POST['fromClient2']; // string2
```

4) let PHP server decode $receivedStr1 and $receivedStr2 into plain texts

I have looked at https://github.com/RNCryptor/RNCryptor, but it's all about **NSData** encryption.

How do you receive **encrypted** **NSData** in PHP?? I only know how to use

```
$fromClient = $_POST['someData'];
```

but it won't work if the whole parameter is encrypted...

Can anyone help me out?? The purpose of this is to send the user's password( = NSString) to PHP server securely.

Comment: Why not take your encrypted NSData and create a base64 endcoded NSString to use for the POST content using `NSData` method `- (NSString *)base64EncodedStringWithOptions:(NSDataBase64EncodingOptions)options`. At the PHP end convert it back to data using `base64_decode`, then decrypt it.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Following on from @Rory McKinnel, this code converts data into a base64 string which can be converted back into plain text or data ([look here for more info](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Base64)).

To convert data in Objective-C:

```
NSString *base64String = [myData base64EncodedStringWithOptions:0];
```

Or in Swift:

```
let base64String = myData.base64EncodedStringWithOptions(options: 0)
```

EDIT:

`NSString` has two useful methods : 1) `- (NSString *)stringByAddingPercentEscapesUsingEncoding:(NSStringEncoding)encoding` and `- (NSString *)stringByAddingPercentEncodingWithAllowedCharacters:(NSCharacterSet *)allowedCharacters`.

These methods help convert an NSString into a **legal URL string**
according to the docs these methods return:

> A new string made by replacing in the receiver all percent escapes with the matching characters as determined by the given encoding encoding. Returns nil if the transformation is not possible, for example, the percent escapes give a byte sequence not legal in encoding.

Comment: I posted using (NSString *parameter = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"data=%@",base64String];), but ($output = base64_decode($_POST['data']);) returns null

Comment: @Joon.P Have you printed out the base64 data sent and the base64 data received for the POST at both ends to check it has sent the complete content properly. Most likely reason for a nil return is invalid input data.

Comment: Yes. In xcode, this is what i got as NSLog for the parameter being sent:
AwGKyXoWznR1apQr2bOQ452JxsBWhq2UApfDZcusK+Yc8UZvMCqxl55MUieg3nQguG3mBlLuFLYZ+M/gm3Qi0whAqdPfNZ7pOZvJ3MSX+2oSjW3UEVe7u93mCC/2k5gpjkU=

and in server, (echo $_POST['data']) printed :
AwGKyXoWznR1apQr2bOQ452JxsBWhq2UApfDZcusK Yc8UZvMCqxl55MUieg3nQguG3mBlLuFLYZ M/gm3Qi0whAqdPfNZ7pOZvJ3MSX 2oSjW3UEVe7u93mCC/2k5gpjkU=


I realized all '+' signs are gone in PHP. and decoding base64 returns nil (echo base64_decode($_POST['data']);)

Comment: Before sending, convert the base64 encoding using: `base64String = [base64String stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@"+" withString:@"%2B"];`. The problem is that + is being stripped out. See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14802715/base64-over-http-post-losing-data-objective-c

Comment: Check out the useful `NSString` methods for escape encoding strings to make a legal URL string (see EDIT in answer)

Comment: Let's not call base64 encoding "encryption". base64 will make already-encrypted data safe to transfer as ASCII, but it's not encryption.

Comment: My bad. Overlooked that as I was answering.

Comment: Rory McKinnel's comment solved my problem. thank you!