# base64_decode is losing whitespace

Tags: php, mysql, sql, sql-server, base64

The PHP Function base64 is losing the whitespace of a decoded string.

For example:

```html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```

When I use the base64_decode function, it results in

```html
#Create table actief CREATE TABLE `actief` ( `actief_id` int(1) NOT NULL, `actief_oms` varchar(15) NOT NULL ) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1; #Dump data INSERT INTO actief SET actief_id='0',actief_oms='niet actief'; INSERT INTO actief SET actief_id='1',actief_oms='actief'; #Create table backup CREATE TABLE `backup` ( `backup_id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT, `datum_last_bu` date NOT NULL, `datum_next_bu` date NOT NULL, `klant_id` int(11) NOT NULL, `bu_name` varchar(60) NOT NULL, `bu_pad` varchar(60) NOT NULL, `bu_mail_to` varchar(60) NOT NULL, `datum` timestamp NOT NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP, PRIMARY KEY (`backup_id`) ) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=2 DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1; #Dump data INSERT INTO backup SET backup_id='1',datum_last_bu='2016-10-01',datum_next_bu='2016-10-04',klant_id='0',bu_name='backup.sql',bu_pad='../backup_my/',bu_mail_to='info@petervankroonenburg.nl',datum='0000-00-00 00:00:00'; #Create table bericht CREATE TABLE `bericht` ( `bericht_id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT, `datum_ontv` datetime DEFAULT NULL, `onderwerp` varchar(140) DEFAULT NULL, `bericht` text, `status` int(2) DEFAULT '1', `
```

But actually, there a some whitespaces... How to solve this?

Comment: Are you using MySQL or MS SQL Server?

Comment: check this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14802715/base64-over-http-post-losing-data-objective-c

Answer (score -2, accepted):

You can use the HTML-tag pre, like this:

```html
<?php
echo "<pre>" . base64_decode($str) . "</pre>";
?>
```

and it results in readable information with the wanted whitespaces :)

Comment: Yes, I had this problem a couple of days ago and I wanted to share the solution :)

Comment: Neither is `base64_decode` loosing white space nor is you answer the fix to this non-existing problem. It is simply that iif you display data as HTML (as you do) then new lines or multiple white space will be treated as a single white space  unless it is inside a preformatted (`<pre>`) section. That's how HTML works.